# how to release connection back to CachingClientConnectionFactory pool in spring integration module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, netty

I am trying to make use of spring integration module to establish a TCP socket connection for request-response model , where I am using CachingClientConnectionFactory, however I see the connections are not released back to pool for reuse, instead new connections are getting created on each request: below is the code snippet being used

Below is the code snippet, i tried using

```
@Bean("clientConnectionFactoryForOutbound")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryForOutbound() {
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setConnectTimeout(5);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(customSerializerDeserializer());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(customSerializerDeserializer());
    var cachingClientConnectionFactory = new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, 3);
    cachingClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
    return cachingClientConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler outboundGateway(@Qualifier("clientConnectionFactoryForOutbound") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName("unsolicitedChannel");
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outboundChannel")
public interface OutboundMessageGateway {

    byte[] sendAndReceive(byte[] message);

}


@Override
public byte[] sendMessage(byte[] message) throws InterruptedException {

    var responseBytes =
        outboundMessageGateway.sendAndReceive(message);
   
    return responseBytes;
}
}
```

Expecting the connection to get released back to cachingClientConnectionFactory pool for reuse on next request, instead the connection is closed and new connections are getting created on every sendMessage call

Answer (score 0):

You must not use:

```
cachingClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
```

It is ignored:

```
/**
 * Ignored on this factory; connections are always cached in the pool. The underlying
 * connection factory will have its singleUse property coerced to true (causing the
 * connection to be returned). Setting it to false on the underlying factory after initialization
 * will cause cache starvation.
 * @param singleUse the singleUse.
 */
@Override
public void setSingleUse(boolean singleUse) {
    if (!singleUse && logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("singleUse=false is not supported; cached connections are never closed");
    }
}
```

Would be great to have the whole simple project from you to let us reproduce and play with. I see there is a scenario when connection is closed forcefully:

```
    if (replyMessage == null) {
        logger.debug(() -> "Remote Timeout on " + connectionId);
        // The connection is dirty - force it closed.
        this.connectionFactory.forceClose(connection);
```

So, be sure that you server indeed returns a reply to your client.